# R Convert data frame to iterable list

Tags: r

Dummy data:

```
nTargets <- 3

df.1 <- data.frame(
  label = paste0('l', 1:nTargets),
  mean  = runif(nTargets,1,10),
  sd    = runif(nTargets,1,3))


> targets
    label     mean       sd
  1    l1 3.458993 1.708791
  2    l2 6.750544 1.662369
  3    l3 5.776566 1.627535
```

I would like a function that converts the frame into an array of lists with fields given by the column names.

I have tried:

```
iterator <- function(df){
  apply( df , 1 , function(f){ as.list(f) } )
}
```

Example usage,

```
df.2 <- NULL # storage
nSamples <- 5
for(d in iterator(df.1)){
   df.2 <- rbind(df.2, data.frame(label=d$label, value=rnorm(nSamples, d$mean, d$sd)))
}
```

The problem with the above is that my function `iterator` converts this to a matrix meaning that `d$mean` and `d$sd` are in fact characters and the call to `rnorm` fails. I could easily fix this up with `as.numeric` but what I really want is to fix the function `iterator` so that the example usage succeeds without casting the values to characters. Any ideas welcome, and thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal, but this seems to fit the bill: `iterator <- function(df)  split(df, df[["label"]])`

Comment: Actually, how about `split(df.1, 1:3)` ?

Comment: alternatively, `iterator <- function(df) plyr::dlply(df, "label", I)`, but this begs the question: why do you need this no-op?

Comment: @baptiste how does that [beg the question](http://begthequestion.info/)? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. `iterator <- function(df) split(df, 1:ncol(df))` works exactly as I need. General function required as the frame just stores parameters to call python routines and these parameters vary between frames. Hence the looping!

Comment: `ncol` should be `nrow` in previous comment

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you could use `split()` to do what you're looking for exactly:

```
split(df, seq_len(ncol(df)))
```

Here's another way to do this using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT = setDT(df.1)
DT[,rnorm(nSamples, mean, sd), by=label]
split(result, result$label)
```

Result:

```
$l1
   label        V1
1:    l1 0.2374258
2:    l1 4.3223959
3:    l1 6.8198647
4:    l1 2.9070670
5:    l1 5.9078326

$l2
   label       V1
1:    l2 9.182992
2:    l2 4.083746
3:    l2 8.899143
4:    l2 9.118341
5:    l2 2.515886

$l3
   label       V1
1:    l3 6.414309
2:    l3 7.162507
3:    l3 7.024702
4:    l3 8.071417
5:    l3 7.673151
```

Comment: Thanks @sheffien. As you point out in the above comments a solution using split works perfectly. `iterator <- function(df) split(df, 1:ncol(df))`.

Comment: `ncol` should be `nrow` in previous